# Do you need a mobilel responsive library for this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile, mobile

If one were to develop an app for mobile devices and it has a fixed layout. Not so responsive. Mainly with a maximum width of 320 and 480x pixels. No iPads. I don't need the elements and layout to move dynamically based on a width. Also without the fancy stuff that normally comes with these libraries. Like fluid grid layouts, list components, fancy animation and swipe detection, buttons, etc.

Whats the purpose of using something like Foundation, or jQuery mobile? Wouldn't rolling your own CSS (and possible JS) be more sensible?

I think it's also worth noting. That I only plan on supporting mobile devices for 4-5 pages. Until we roll out our native app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **CSS media queries**, which are supported by Rails out of the box:

General information: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

General example: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Rails related: http://crimpycode.brennonbortz.com/?p=7